# Pentaho report viewer not working properly after adding requestParameterProcessingFilter for api url pattern

Tags: pentaho

Pentaho report viewer is not working properly after adding **requestParamerterProcessingFilter** for api url api/**

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
      <value>
        <![CDATA[CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /webservices/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /plugin/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionReuseDetectionFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor]]>
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

**Issue** is Only default report view is displaying. If we change to pdf or some other view , it is once again displaying default view ( html) instead of pdf view.

Can anybody have idea why it is showing like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-10708 and the latest comment there. It will help you get over those Reporting errors

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro Vale Thanks,

By adding this pattern  /api/repos/**/parameter 
Problem solved.

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
      <value>
        <![CDATA[CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /webservices/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/repos/**/parameter=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /api/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS        
        /plugin/**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterForWS,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,basicProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilterForWS,filterInvocationInterceptorForWS
        /**=securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,httpSessionPentahoSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,httpSessionReuseDetectionFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,basicProcessingFilter,requestParameterProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor]]>
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```